# Running Python 3 interpreter in PyCharm Community Edition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am a new PyCharm user who switched from Wing.

In Wing, if I configure Wing to use the "Python3" interpreter, the console would also run Python3. However, in PyCharm Community Version, even if I configure the project to use the Python 3.4 interpreter, the console would still use 2.7.5. (The program runs properly with Python 3.4) Is there a way that I can use the console with Python3.

Platform: Mac OS X 10.7.5
Python 2.7.5 and 3.4 installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to `Settings > Console > Python Console` you can choose the standard interpreter for your console.

The standard there is the chosen Project Interpreter you select under `Settings > Project Interpreter`. Don't forget to restart Pycharm.

Or you can assign a different interpreter to each project. Go to `Settings > Project:myproject > Project Interpreter`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the Project Interpreter and the Console Interpreter is the same setting.