# How to install M2Crypto for python in Windows x64

Tags: python, python-3.x, m2crypto

I need to use M2Crypto in my python script. I downloaded the M2Crypto windows installer from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2CryptoWin64

When I imported the M2Crypto in my script using: `import M2Crypto` and run my script, I get errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/TLSscanner/scanner_v2.py", line 4, in <module>
    from M2Crypto.Err import SSLError
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\TLSscanner\M2Crypto\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import __m2crypto
ImportError: No module named '__m2crypto'
```

I do not know where to place the M2Crypto folder after I installed it and extracted it? Can you clarify to me where packages need to be placed in order for the script to run?

**EDIT:**
This is the successful installation path. Shall I put my python script in the same path? The error I get when running my script (in another folder for the project) is shown above.
[image]

Comment: Install with the specified pip invocation on the page you linked.

Comment: I did. But still when I run the python script I get errors. Where should the package files be stored extactly? Where should I change the directory to be before I run the command?

Comment: The command will download the file. What are the errors?

Comment: The error is posted in the question.

Comment: Please use text not screenshots for error messages. Looks like it installed fine. Most likely your pycharm needs to be configured to use your python3.5 install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python 3 interpreter in PyCharm Community Edition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692052/running-python-3-interpreter-in-pycharm-community-edition)

Comment: It is using python3.5. I have also python3.6b. I tried both and the problem is not solved.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/41251991/164233 (TL;DR M2Crypto hasn't been working with Python 3 yet)